# How to remove front forks on motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, suspension, forks

I've got my motorcycle up in the air about to pull the frame up off the engine but I need to remove one last thing.  I got everything taken apart except this center bolt holding the front forks on.  How do I get this bolt out or how do I get the front forks off
2012 YAMAHA R6

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You will require the appropriate spanner wrench to remove the primary bolt and the locking bolt.

Here is an image

[image]

Once you have removed the bolts you will be able to remove the top plate of the triple tree and the bottom portion will stay attached to the forks.

Best of luck.

Comment: I **strongly** recommend getting a spanner that has a drive cutout so you can properly follow the torquing procedure, such as this [Bikemaster adjustable steering stem wrench](http://www.bikemaster.com/tools/adjustable-steering-stem-wrench.html).